# SQL Server Case Statement not working

Tags: sql-server, case

Background info: C# code calls this stored procedure to produce an output CSV with the logic applied in the SQL case statements.

**Problem**: the below SQL `CASE` statement executes successfully, but the issue is that it doesn't give me the correct values in the output CSV file that gets generated when it comes down to `cl.AB_Receive_Frequency`.

```
CASE
   WHEN cl.Product_Type IN ('SwapCrossCurrency', 'Swap', 'Swaption', 'SwapNonDeliverable', 'CapFloor') 
      THEN 
         CASE
            WHEN cl.Rcv_Leg_Type = 'Float' 
                 AND cl.AB_Receive_Leg_Reset_Frequency = 'Weekly' 
               THEN '1'
            WHEN cl.Rcv_Leg_Type = 'Float' 
                 AND cl.AB_Receive_Leg_Reset_Frequency = '' 
               THEN 
                  CASE
                     WHEN cl.AB_Receive_Frequency IN ('WK', 'BIWK') 
                        THEN 'W'
                     WHEN cl.AB_Receive_Frequency IN ('LUN', 'ZC') 
                        THEN 'D'
                     WHEN cl.AB_Receive_Frequency IN ('MTH', 'BIM', 'QA', 'SA', 'QTR') 
                        THEN 'M'
                     WHEN cl.AB_Receive_Frequency = 'PA' 
                        THEN 'Y'
                  END
            WHEN cl.Rcv_Leg_Type = 'Fixed' 
               THEN ''
         END
END
```

Can anyone see why this wouldn't work?

Comment: That parses so you have a logic problem. Add `ELSE` defaults to see whats not matching or simplify it adding bits back and test until it stops doing what you expect.  Make sure AB_Receive_Leg_Reset_Frequency is not NULL instead of ''. Consider defining the `('WK', 'BIWK') THEN 'W'` relationships in a table & JOINing.

Comment: Update question with a single sample record that isn't working the way you expect with the product_Type, rcv_leg_Type, ab_receive_leg_Reset_Frequency and Ab._receive_Frequency values.  Maybe change   `WHEN cl.Rcv_Leg_Type = 'Float' 
                 AND cl.AB_Receive_Leg_Reset_Frequency = ''` to   `WHEN cl.Rcv_Leg_Type = 'Float' 
                 AND cl.AB_Receive_Leg_Reset_Frequency <> 'Weekly'`? so the whole set is managed?

Comment: @xQbert, without more information we can't rule out the possibility of cl.AB_Receive_Leg_Reset_Frequency IS NULL.

Comment: Nod; which is why I asked for a sample record. that wasn't achieving the desired result and said Maybe.

Comment: @AlexK.  Dragon Non of the above work. What about the order/ nesting of the statement

Comment: @xQbert Non of the above work. What about the order/ nesting of the statement

Comment: Without a sample record failing to meet expectations I've nothing more to add